# Java: how to resize an image on the gpu

Tags: java, image, directx, rendering, gpu

I have an application that needed to resize a lot of big grayscale images (up to 4000 * 4000).
I don't want to use java graphics because it works on the CPU. Is there a way to perform resize on the GPU similar to directX9::StretchRect.
In stretchRect I get the resize and the rendering in a single step.

Comment: I would try JavaCL or JavaCV which allows you to program the GPU. However, it may be simpler to use the CPU and even a image of this size may not take that long.

Comment: I'm not persuaded that an image re-size will be that much faster on a GPU with the I/O transfer latency.  I suggest you first try running ImageJ on a different thread.  After all, most CPUs today have more than one core.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with scaling that makes it (sometimes) not that friendly to parallelization (Which is the reason people use GPUs) is the need for interpolation during scaling. More specifically, the averaging of color values from surrounding pixels to get the value for the new pixel (when expanding) or averaging all surrounding pixels intelligently into a single color value that you try and represent multiple pixels by (when shrinking).

This requires you to know all the values around a given pixels which means all the rows above/below/left/right of the pixels need to be ready-to-be-read.

I am sure you can do image scaling on the GPU, I just don't think you'll get high-quality scaling that is super-parallelized in which case doing it on the CPU is likely what you want here.

If there is some unique aspect to the image scaling that you are doing where it *can* be seriously parallelized and each row or set of rows can be averaged out without the image data round them, then yes that would be an excellent thing to push to the GPU.